# Theorem 4.4 from linear algebra by Friedberg

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

In the last line, the second equality follows from the preceding lemma, but I am struggling with the first equality. I have a theorem that $\det$ is a linear function of each row when the remaining rows are fixed. Therefore, if 
$$\det(A) = \det(\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_j),$$
the first equality holds and there is no problem. But, I don't think that $A =\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_j$. Could you give some help?

Comment: In the future, please always name the book you're quoting from, particularly when the proof refers to a previous theorem that you haven't quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not, but you misunderstood the linearity.

Let $B_j'$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing row $i$ of $A$ with $A_{ij}e_j.$ Then we have
$$\det A=\det\sum_{j=1}^nB_j'=\sum_{j=1}^n\det B_j'=\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}\det B_j,$$
where the second equality is by the property of determinants you mentioned and the last equality is by the scaling property of determinants and the definition of $B_j.$

Comment: I didn't know the scaling property. It makes sense now. Thanks!